# Error Function definitions are not permitted in this context

Tags: matlab

I have these four lines written in a file called `abc.m`

```
function [x, y] = abc(q, r)
    x=q;
    y=r;
end
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, I first get a popup that says

> The selected section cannot be evaluated because it contains an invalid statement

Then in the command prompt it says:

```
function [x,y]=abc(q,r)
↑
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
```

I have read the other questions on this error, and I do not understand why this simple file wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, this is the equivalent of [**Run Selection**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html#brqxeeu-263) which will execute a code block surrounded by `%%`'s. The code in this code block is run *as a script* which essentially copies and executes the lines of your code block one at a time in the command window. In all current versions of MATLAB, you cannot define a function within a script or directly within the command window, which is the cause for your error.

If you simply want to execute your function, you will want to use **Run** (or <kbd>F5</kbd>) to do so which will run the entire file, as a function.